# Сохранять изменения html кода с помощью JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html

Имеется html файл с простейшей формой:

```
        <table id="tbl">
            <tr>
                <td>Поле раз</td>
                <td>Поле два</td>
                <td>Поле три</td>
                <td>Поле четыре</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td><input type="text" name="field1[]" id="field1" /></td>
                <td><input type="text" name="field2[]" id="field2" /></td>
                <td><input type="text" name="field3[]" id="field3" /></td>
                <td><input type="text" name="field4[]" id="field4" /></td>
                <td><input type="button" onclick="addRow('main');return false;" value="Сохранить"/></td>
            </tr>
        </table>
```

И функция добавления строки таблицы в нем же по клику на клавишу сохранить:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function addRow(id){
    var tbody = document.getElementById(id).getElementsByTagName("TBODY")[0];
    var f1 = document.getElementById("field1").value
    var f2 = document.getElementById("field2").value
    var f3 = document.getElementById("field3").value
    var f4 = document.getElementById("field4").value
    var row = document.createElement("TR")
    var td1 = document.createElement("TD")
    td1.appendChild(document.createTextNode(f1))
    var td2 = document.createElement("TD")
    td2.appendChild (document.createTextNode(f2))
    var td3 = document.createElement("TD")
    td3.appendChild (document.createTextNode(f3))
    var td4 = document.createElement("TD")
    td4.appendChild (document.createTextNode(f4))
    row.appendChild(td1);
    row.appendChild(td2);
    row.appendChild(td3);
    row.appendChild(td4);
    tbody.appendChild(row);
  }
</script>
```

Сделано это все для удобства внесения данных в таблицу, поскольку использовать гугл форму или эксель нет возможности, а блокнот - неудобно :)

В общем, основной вопрос, как прикрутить возможность сохранения полученной таблицы, чтобы после перезагрузки страницы она не сбрасывалась?

Answer (score 1):

Если хотите хранить в "браузере". Я бы смотрел в сторону JSON + localstorage.
https://learn.javascript.ru/localstorage